# Vaadin does not show client side Widget

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, widget, client, vaadin

I know that my question is a bit abstract, but I still think someone can help. I am new to `vaadin` and I have created a simple project (without maven) on which I have added two client widgets in the way described in [the tutorial](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html). The client side widgets are not trivial, since the depend on a class hierarchy which provides them some functionality. In the `Applicationn` class I try to get the Widgets appear in the browser with the simple code:

```
@Override
    public void init() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("My Application");

        setTheme("theme");
        Screen as = new Screen();
        mainWindow.addComponent(as);
        setMainWindow(mainWindow);
    }
```

`Screen` is the server side Widget with the `VScreen` as the client side Widget. However in the browser appear only the images which are set in the server side code. The real functionality of the widget lie in the client side widget but it is not presented on the browser.

It gives me the impression that the client side code does not run at all. What could be a possible reason?

I use Windows 8 and out of an unknown reason it does not allow me to install `GWT Developer Plugin` in `Chrome`, so as to be to able to debug it on the client side. Of course, when I set a breakpoint in the client side code, the default debug does not take it into account, since debug occurs by default only in the server side of a `vaadin` project.

Moreover when I try to extend the class TouchKitApplication in MyApplication included in vaadin add-on, it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

```
public class MyApplication extends TouchKitApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserDetailsReady() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("My Application");

        setTheme("theme");
        Screen as = new Screen();
        mainWindow.addComponent(as);
        setMainWindow(mainWindow);  
    }

}
```

Is somenthing missing in my project?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Vaadin do you use? Because Vaadin 6 uses setTheme() method, but Vaadin 7 uses the @Theme() annotation, and if the theme is not correct that can result the problem of widgets not showing also if in your own theme you do not import the default one that can cause the problem as well

Comment: I use vaadin 6. I don 't think though that theme can prevent widgets from appearing.

Comment: it messes up a lot if the default is not applied, only text stays then, it happened a few days ago to my table widget

Comment: for the ClassNotFoundException, if it's an add-on, you should check if  the jar is in the projects classpath

Comment: It was always in project build path but it wanted it to be under WEB-INF/lib directory.